# What do you need to change the domain of an owncloud installation?

Tags: configuration, dns, owncloud

I need to rename the domain name of an owncloud installation in the near future. The old name will no longer be available.

Besides the change in the webserver configuration itself, and the config for owncloud is there the need to do other changes, like in the database, for instance?

Comment: Why don't you simply install a backup of your owncloud in the new host and try? You have to test that anyway, how else do you want to move the data?

Comment: @arkasha Well, because if I can jump over some pitfalls, and save some time, that is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the trusted domains in the config.php. I would also recommend to upgrade to Nextcloud. It is the more active and secure project.

Comment: The recommendation to upgrade to `nextcloud` is a purely personal opinion and should not be part of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, no other change should be needed.